# Cable connector order causing USB to break

Tags: usb, connector, esd

We have a system that's using nonstandard connectors (M12) to provide 24V power from one device to another, along with USB lines. Each system has ESD protection on its usb lines.

The issue is that when you plug in the cable, sometimes power and USB will make contact before ground. This causes lots of current to flow through the usb lines, breaking the ESD protection and the devices connected to the bus:

[image]

Is there anything we can do to fix this, other than changing the connectors (to be special purpose make first break last, or standard usb)?

Comment: Can you edit your drawing to include the connector locations? It might be possible to come up with something. USB connectors have the make first break last feature for the power and GND for a reason, it's easy and reliable.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMowHb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The relay simulates your connector mating and un-mating.
You may need to tweak the R & C values a little, depending on the P-MOSFET you choose.

Comment: It seems like this works for ground being removed before power, but doesnt work for ground being attached after power, unless i'm missing something?

Comment: @BeB00 - the R2/R3 voltage divider needs to be adjusted such that with ground not connected there isn't enough voltage across R2 and the pMOS gate-source to switch it on. In fact it might be better to replace R3 with something like a 20V zener. The sum of this zener and the USB protection should be roughly equal to your supply, while the supply voltage minus the zener voltage should be high enough to switch the pMOS on hard...